# GitKracken does not connect to Gitlab

Tags: gitkraken

Currently, when you select the "Connect to Gitlab" button in the GK preferences it opens a login page for regular gitlab...

`https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in`

However, I have a local version of Gitlab accessible via

`https://gitlab.henryJack.com/`

Is there a way to get GitKracken to look at my local version of gitlab?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I feel you. My GitKraken does not even open the browser when I click on "Connect to GitLab"

Comment: See my updated answer, seems like their offering has changed. The Pro version now offers what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK GitKraken does not support any GitLab instances except `gitlab.com`.

Your best bet is to set up an "`Other Connection`", i.e. read https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/other-connection

**Edit 2017-12-26:**

According to [GitKrakens features page](https://www.gitkraken.com/features) the Pro version now supports what you are asking for.